# VS 2022 Adding Web Reference in WinService project

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on a migration project (Windows service) and I tried updating the web reference, which is pointing to the old server, by deleting the existing and adding a new one.

I tried following the approach used in the following article but endup having some issues, as detailed below
https://adevsolvedit.com/4/visual-studio-2022-2019-add-web-reference-missing

**Issue:** After clicking the advance button from the bottom left corner, I'm getting the error as shown in the second image. Also, I don't find any additional details in the ErrorList or Output tab of the Visual Studio 2022.

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.